# redirect site.com/board to newsite.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect (rewrite via htaccess) requests from "site.com/board" to "newsite.com" while preserving the structure and all the parameters. Tell me how to do it correctly?
list of old structure (site.com):

```
1. site.com/board/category 
2. site.com/board/category/subcategory
3. site.com/board/category/subcategory/city
4. site.com/board/category/subcategory/city?someparam=1&param=2...
and other site.com/board/register (login, page, terms...)
```

Is there a universal solution
what should i write in .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

**I found :)**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/board/(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newsite.com/%1 [R=301,L]
```